# Do messages in dead letter queues in Azure Service Bus expire?

Tags: c#, azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

Do messages in dead letter queues in Azure Service Bus expire?

### Some explanation

I have these queue settings:

```
var queueDescription = new QueueDescription("MyTestQueue")
{
    RequiresSession = false,
    DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true,
    MaxDeliveryCount = 10
};

namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queueDescription);
```

When I place some messages in a Azure Service Bus message queue (not queues from Azure Storage) and don't consume them (ever), they'll be moved to the dead letter queue automatically.

However, if I have no consumer for the dead letter queue either, will the messages ever be deleted from the dead letter queue or will they stay there forever? (Is there some official documentation stating how this is supposed to work?)

### My Trials

In my trials, I placed *3 messages* in the queue. They were dead lettered after 2 minutes or so. They remained in the dead letter queue for at least a day and weren't removed.

[image: Message Queue Statistics]

Although calling [NamespaceManager.GetQueueAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn130225%28v=VS.100,d=hv.2%29.aspx) gave me the values above (notice how `MessageCount` is still `3` but `DeadLetterMessageCount` is strangely `0`), I could still receive the messages from the dead letter queue. (So they weren't removed from the queue.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sebastian your observation is correct, in that messages once placed in the DeadLetter sub-queue never expire. They will be available there forever until removed explicitly from the DeadLetter sub-queue. In the above error regarding the tooling/api it could be a refresh issue? The call to GetQueueAsync() needs to be made after the messages have been dead-lettered which is not a deterministic time, say if you had a queue with a thousand messages that were expired but that Queue was not being used (send/receive operations) then the count may still return as Active until some operations are performed.

Comment: Basically: Make sure the queues are regularly deleted, possibly in a sensible way (i.e. processed in some way, errors thrown etc.).

Answer (score 4):

After doing some research I stumbled over a fact I missed completely:

**Messages can expire even when dead lettering is disabled.**

When messages expire while dead lettering is disabled (which is the default), they'll just get deleted.

So, Microsoft's reasoning for not auto-deleting messages from the dead letter queue is probably:

*If you're enabling dead lettering, you **explicitly** want expired message not to be thrown away but stored somewhere else (the dead letter queue) so that you can review them.*

Comment: could you provide the source for this info? 

"Messages can expire even when dead lettering is disabled"

I tried looking up and could not find this stated anywhere

Comment: Upvoted because I like the comment. I do believe there also may be a case where we want to dead letter message so that we dont have loss of data, but still have some type of expiration of messages which reside on deadletter queue. Just a thought.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/main/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.ServiceBus.json#L990