# ServiceBusTrigger function not executing

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I am using the ServiceBusTrigger attribute (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/)

I create a message using the following code, which works, I see it in the queue:

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(QueueConnectionString, queueName);
var dto = (AdListingServiceBusDto) obj;
client.Send(new BrokeredMessage(dto));
```

Now in my intake program I have the following code setup to retrieve the message (web job):

```
static void Main()
{
    var _servicesBusConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsServiceBus"].ConnectionString;
    JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration
    {
        ServiceBusConnectionString = _servicesBusConn
    };

    JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}

public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("wordpress-post")] BrokeredMessage dto, TextWriter logger)
{
    logger.WriteLine(dto);
}
```

I used Service Bus Explorer and I see one message in the "wordpress-post" queue, I see the message text as "40 12 43 75 73 74 6F 6D 65 72 4F 72 64 65 72 45 76 65 6E 74 08 1A 68 74 74 70".. etc so I know the message is there but the function never gets triggered (I have a breakpoint on it)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does changing the first parameter in your ProcessQueueMessage method from a BrokeredMessage to a String work? I know your adding it as a BrokeredMessage and it looks right to me. I'm curious if changing it to a string works though.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Maybe your messages are in the DeadLetterMessage queue. Check it out with Fiddler, the first call will be a GET

GET /your-queue/?api-version=2015-08 HTTP/1.1

The CountDetails will have the values.

Other things to have a look at: [Do messages in dead letter queues in Azure Service Bus expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626995/do-messages-in-dead-letter-queues-in-azure-service-bus-expire)