# Delete messages from the DLQ after a specified period such as six months

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Azure Service Bus entities (queues/topics) support a Time to Live (TTL). When the TTL passes the message expires. On expiry, the system deletes the message OR moves it to the Dead-Letter Queue (DLQ). **Does Service Bus have another setting to delete messages from the DLQ after a specified period?** For instance, to avoid passing size quotas, we might like to delete messages from the DLQ after six months.

See also:

[Do messages in dead letter queues in Azure Service Bus expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626995/do-messages-in-dead-letter-queues-in-azure-service-bus-expire)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Service Bus doesn't have an expiration option on the dead-letter queues. This is likely intentional, as the system shouldn't just lose those messages but rather do something about them.

Sometimes, monitoring all dead-letter queues for total size and whatnot is inconvenient. One option is to create a centralized DLQ. That will allow the following:

1. Monitoring a single "dead-letter" queue.
2. Receive messages from a single entity for processing.
3. Keep the size under control by specifying a TTL on the queue.

For example, let's say you've got two queues, `test-dlq` and `test-dlq2`. You'd configure those to auto-forward dead-lettered messages to a 3rd queue, `test-dlq-all`. With that, when you have messages that are received by `test-dlq` or `test-dlq2` and dead-lettering,

[image: state 1]

Those messages will end up in the centralized "DLQ" queue (`test-dlq-all`).

[image: state 2]

The nice part is whenever you have messages auto-forwarded, you'll always know where they originally dead-lettered.

For example, let's say you've got two messages, each from a different queue, ending up in `test-dlq-all`, the centralized "DLQ".

[image: state 3]

Inspecting its messages will reveal a system property, `DeadLetterSource`, stamped with the name of the queue it was dead-lettered initially in.

[image: state 4]

This solution lets you set TTL on the `test-dlq-all` queue and have messages auto-perged.

Also, worth mentioning that it's possible to either set up dead-lettering with the centralized "DLQ" or get messaged dead-lettered as a result of failing processing that exceeds `MaxDeliveryCount`. For that reason, it is worth wither monitoring `test-dlq-all`s DLQ.

Comment: Does forwarding support a delay? _Forward this message after 3 days._

Comment: No, it does not.